# OpenGL code doesn't show anything in window mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, windows-10, nvidia

I wanna create a program with OpenGL in my PC. I use this code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>

bool bFullsreen = false;
int nWindowID;

void display(void)
{
    //Clear all pixels
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //draw white polygon (rectangle) with corners at
    // (0.25, 0.25, 0.0) and (0.75, 0.75, 0.0)
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    // Don't wait start processing buffered OpenGL routines)
    //glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void init(void)
{
    //select clearing (background) color
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    //initialize viewing values 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}

void keyboardFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {

    switch (key) {
    case 'f':

        bFullsreen = !bFullsreen;
        if (bFullsreen)
            glutFullScreen();
        else {
            glutSetWindow(nWindowID);
            glutPositionWindow(100, 100);
            glutReshapeWindow(640, 480);
        }
        break;

    }
}

void idleFunc(void) {
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int _tmain(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(250,250);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    nWindowID = glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunc);
    glutIdleFunc(idleFunc);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

when i run it in my PC it coesn't show anything and only show background. like this picture:

[image]

But when I switch to FullScreen mode, it shows correctly. I searched about it and I found changing `GLUT_Single` to `GLUT_DOUBLE` and `glFlush()` to `glutSwapBuffers()` but it doesn't work for me.

I have windows 10 with NVIDIA GForce 7300 LE. when I run my program in other PC it runs correctly. so 
What is my problem? Is it about my graphic card or my code is incorrect? and
How can I fixed it?

Comment: you can try glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE) from http://www-etud.iro.umontreal.ca/~clavetsi/api/glut/glutInitDisplayMode.html

Comment: Y'all are using [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), right?  Not [the 15 year old Nate Robins build](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html)?

Comment: @Mozfox I use 'glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)' but still have this error.

Comment: @genpfault, Yes, I am using FreeGLUT. Do you recommand use this build?

Comment: @Rabbid76, I said it works on other PC. I think it ma about NVIDIA graphic card. Is it correct or not? cand how can I run it in windows 10?

Comment: Anything change if you use `glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I Changed it but still I have that error. Note: my NVIDIA graphic card doesn't have Windows 10 driver and I installed Windows 7 driver. Is it the reason?

Comment: @genpfault I changed it but I have that error too. Do you have any recommendation?